# twitter bootstrap prepend width too big on mibile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a website using twitter bootstrap 2.3 and have a problem with inputs on mobile sized screens.

On my contact page one of the inputs is email and has a email icon prepended to it. When the viewport gets down to the size of mobile the responsive.css kicks in and adds width: auto to the prepend class.

The result and issue is this makes the input too long for the screen size and breaks outs.

I am not sure is this a problem with the way I am using it or an issue with twitter bootstrap. This issue does not seem to be reported any where.

**bootstrap-responsive.css**

```
.input-prepend input, .input-append input, .input-prepend input[class*="span"], .input-append input[class*="span"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}
```

The issue can be viewed at

http://www.treacyswestcounty.com/contact-us/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it by adding this to your CSS

```
.input-prepend input {
    width: 179px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is this a know issue with bootstrap do you think?

Comment: It don't know if its know or not but I believe it's definitely an issue